# upload large file to s3 in the fastest manner

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-lambda

I'd like a file of 1-2GB to be uploaded to `s3` from a `lambda` function. I need for it to be optimized enough to happen in seconds, not minutes.

Programming Lang: NodeJS with Typescript

What's the best way to ensure that?

Comment: Use an AWS SDK with Transfer Manager that will upload via Multi-part Copy. You did not specify a programming language, so I can't be more specific. Is the source file stored on the filesystem inside the Lambda function? If so, please note that you'll need to increase the storage allocated to the function, which defaults to 512MB. Feel free to Edit your Question to provide more information about your situation. 2GB is not a particularly large file.

Comment: The source would be data coming in from Athena which I will format with a handlebar template in a lambda function and then forward to reporting microservice (by moving data to a specific location in s3 ) as that huge data set will not fit in the payload of HTTP request.

Comment: So what will the Lambda function be doing? Sending a SELECT to Athena, then (somehow) sending the results to S3? Receiving data from Athena is going to take much more time than sending the result to S3. Depending on how you want the data formatted, you could simply have Athena store the output in S3 directly and then optionally copy it elsewhere. It all depends on what format you want in the files.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am looking to optimize the workflow basically. Evaluating if Athena will do it for us. Data gets streamed into the S3 lake. Let's say The user requests a report at 7:04 pm for data until 7:03 pm starting last year. The idea is that reporting microservice will kick off a shared "doc generation service" which will shoot an Athena query that will "UNLOAD" the results in JSON format. This UNLOAD should kick off a lambda that formats the data in the expected format and will pass data to the respective handlebar template and then convert HTML to PDF.

Comment: I have explained it better here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73328293/optimize-the-process-of-report-generation-tool-recommendations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the AWS SDK for JavaScript, you can upload parts in parallel, for code samples also [check this great post](https://ankan101.medium.com/how-to-upload-large-files-to-aws-s3-8be5d6da8374).

By uploading in parallel you will use the max bandwidth available to your lambda and since it is done async you won't block the thread, so you will achieve faster upload speed.